# How to keep using git after switch from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: android, linux, git, ubuntu, github

I swapped my OS from Windows to Ubuntu and after installing Android Studio I copied my projects into the new AndroidStudioProjects so the.git folders are in there too. Now, how could I keep tracking my projects to my Github from the same progress I was when I was using windows? Sorry if stupid question btw.

Comment: If you pushed to the remote repo from windows, you should be able to seamlessly clone it in Linux. Your platform makes no difference here. If you just copied the directory, s long as you also copied the .git director, you do not need to reclone, and continue working out of the copied directory. Again, as long as you kept that `.git` directory, there should be no change.

Comment: @MattClark I did copy the .git directory. But if I do git status on the project directory all the files come in red as if they are not being tracked. This is what worried me.

Answer (score 1):

> I did copy the .git directory. But if I do git status on the project directory all the files come in red as if they are not being tracked. This is what worried me.

If you copied only the .git folder, git detect that all the files of the working directory has been deleted.

The only thing you have to do is to restore them.

Beware, verify that your working directory is really empty or you could loose files.

If that's the case, just run:

```
 git checkout .
```

Or (that should be the same) :

```
  git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: [This is what I mean](http://i.imgur.com/bK5wpp4.png). I migrated my project exactly how I had it in Windows and if I run git status on it I see [this](http://i.imgur.com/yOrwdzZ.png). But I haven't made any modification to those files.

Comment: You don't have a '.gitattributes' file (which is a good practice), so I think it is a problem with the eol/autocrlf setting. If you did not have changes in the working directory before migration, you still can run my commands, that will fix the problem. Otherwise, it will more difficult...